# Applying the same changes for one div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

The following code makes some changes with `class1` inside of `.main` and its (`class1`) content.

```
$('.main').on('click','.class1',function(){
   //some work with $(this)
});
```

Also, there is a `div.class2` inside of `.main` that has similar structure as `div.class1` has.

The question is:
What is the easiest way to apply all changes that happen to class1 by the code above by clicking on `.class1` to class2 as well?

Cloning `div.class1` to `div.class2` is not the way to go as the content is slightly different. Only the code that's being executed above should be applied to both `class1` and `class2`.

What important is the code above contains `.closest()` method like this `$(this).closest('.bar')`.

Comment: Put a common class on both elements and put that in the selector.

Comment: closest will always return just 1 item.  If you have to use it try finding the closest parent that wraps both class1 and class2 and apply the style to the children.

Comment: Can you show us the exact structure of your html, and where `closest()` fits into this? What are you *really* trying to do when clicking on either div element?

Comment: @Jamiec, I'm really sorry I can't share the whole code. The question was if it is possible for any code. Adding a common class was a nice idea, however, it doesn't work. Doing something like replacing $this with class1, class2 all together.  There is probably no easier way that to execute the code for this, then find if this is from class1 or from class2, then switch to another class and probably execute the whole code again.

Comment: do u want ur changes to happen to class2 also everytime someone clicks class1 ? in this case, no one is touching class2  (or) is it that u want same change to happen when both are clicked separately ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine multiple selectors by using a comma:

```
$('.main').on('click','.class1, .class2',function(){
   //some work with $(this)
});
```

But I would like to recommend you to use a common class for them.

```
$('.main').on('click','.common_class',function(){
   //some work with $(this)
});
```

You can use multiple classes in your html by putting a space between them.

For eg:

```
<div class="class1 common_class"></div>
<div class="class2 common_class"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry it won't work as the code contains closest method like this $(this).closest('.bar'). My fault, I should mention it in the question.

Comment: @Haradzieniec - either option should still work if you use `.closest()`. Inside the handler `$(this)` refers to the actual one clicked on

Comment: @Jamiec, it will find only one closest() and will apply the code exactly to one of class1, class2, but not both.